# When do you check input type when writing class method

Tags: php, validation, coding-style

How would you proceed writing the code when you have multiple inputs like in this example:

```
public function addNameAndAge($name, $age) {
    if (false === is_string($name) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
    }

    // ... same for age but using is_int().
}
```

Do we have to check each of these inputs?

I could rewrite the source code to use PHP 7's type hinting `string $name` and `int $age` which would actually help me/us, but after that we have to check also if the `$name` is empty or the `$age` is not lower or hight than xy.

This variables are really for example. I would be interested how you would guys progress in this kind of situation. Validate everything in every way, or just check the type?

Comment: Honestly, why reinvent the wheel. I'd use a validation library such as https://github.com/Respect/Validation -- and just include it via Composer.

Comment: @HalfCrazed Thank you it looks promising, I will definitely use this library which you have suggested. But I have to clarify that the above snipet method and argument names are example. The input does not come from the user, the method would be used internally maybe by an another method.

Comment: @ZsoltOroszlány - You can still use that library, regardless where the data comes from.

Comment: I will accept @HalfCrazed answer. Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: @ZsoltOroszlány thanks. I added an official answer so you could mark it (yay points). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(converted from comment to answer) Honestly, why reinvent the wheel. I'd use a validation library such as github.com/Respect/Validation -- and just include it via Composer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate arguments, in fact, it is convenient to use some validation library. You can inject it as a dependency.

The important point here, and it regards not only validation but all methods, to **make a method to do one and only one thing**. This is a rule that method should contain 5+/-2 lines of code.

```
class Person
{
    private $name;
    private $age;

    private $validator;

    public function __construct($validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function addNameAndAge($name, $age)
    {
        $this->setName($name)->setAge($age);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        // perform validation here

        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setAge($age)
    {
        // perform validation here

        $this->age = $age;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So if we define setting and validating operation as atomic operation this will work. But if not, we can go even further and extract validations to their own methods.

```
class Person
{
    private $name;
    private $age;

    private $validator;

    public function __construct($validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function addNameAndAge($name, $age)
    {
        $this->setName($name)->setAge($age);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        $this->validateName();

        return $this;
    }

    private function validateName()
    {
        // perform validation here
    }

    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;

        $this->validateAge();

        return $this;
    }

    private function validateAge()
    {
        // perform validation here
    }
}
```

If you careful to set properties with the setters all the time, you don't need to worry about validation except in the setters themselves.